# Doubts on pre-installed applications

Tags: 20.10

I am new to ubuntu, i just noticed some odd things when i was casually using my computer. I noticed that there were 2 file explorers and 1 app know as sharing. I think they got added and are not pre installed. Could i know if they came pre installed with ubuntu?

[image]

Any further help will be helpful!